# Slide in a div from bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to the achieve an affect like the one on this page:

[Slide Up/Down DIV from bottom center of the page using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100084/slide-up-down-div-from-bottom-center-of-the-page-using-jquery)

but I need it to work on page load with 5-6 seconds delay!

can this be done only with CSS or pure javascript? if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: use setTimeout function

Comment: not sure if this possible in CSS ,but this would work and will  be easier in js .

Comment: Use [animation-delay](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-delay) CSS3 property.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: use jquery fadein and fadeout with timer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JQUERY:**

use it with the `window.onload = function ...`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var top = $('#yourID').position().top;
    document.getElementById('youridhere').scrollIntoView();

}, 5000); // your timeout in ms
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

old question, but if anyone finds this through google (as I did) and who does not want to use anchors or jquery there's a builtin javascript function to 'jump' to an element.

```
document.getElementById('youridhere').scrollIntoView();
```

and what's even better, according to the great compatibility-tables on quirksmode, this is [supported by all major browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t23)!

**OR**
You can use an anchor to "focus" the div. I.e:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

and then use the following javascript:

```
// the next line is required to work around a bug in WebKit (Chrome / Safari)
location.href = "#";
location.href = "#myDiv";
```

**And else**
look at this fiddle :)  there is a javascript **only** scroll animation

http://jsfiddle.net/ySeWk/

Comment: The OP is looking for a js solution